# remote_function alternative in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, animation, loading

I'm doing a tutorial for [rails animated loading page](http://www.marketingformavens.com/blog/create-a-page-loading-animation-with-ruby-on-rails-and-ajax) but the problem is that I get the following message **undefined method `remote_function'**.I've done some research and it seems that "remote_function" is deprecated.Can anyone tell me please how to I make the code work on rails 3.1 :

```
onload="<%= remote_function(:url => { :action => :get_content_to_display } ) %>"
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3.1 prefered to use unobtrusive javascript. So you should use javascript framework (for ex. JQuery) to achieve your goal.
In old version of Rails `remove_function` just sent AJAX request to server when it was called.
So you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready ()->
  $.get "your_url", ()->
    #handle response
```

Hope it will help you. And here is some additional info: [JQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: So you should read more about javascript, because it essential part of  web development

Comment: remove `remote_function` call from your view

Comment: I remove `remote _function` but now I got a syntax error, I really have to follow your advide bor1s and do my javascript homework

Comment: Remember that, Rails 3.1 uses Coffescript, so it is indentation sensetive. So please check your indentation.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help bor1s, but I'm gonna quit on this one and go learn javascript right now. I think that it's important to make things work, but i have to fully understand what i'm coding.Thanks for the advice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4982/discussion-between-blawzoo-and-bor1s)

Answer (score 1):

For quick fix of using prototype function in rails 3.1, add prototype_helper in your helpers folder the remote_function will be working fine then.