# ruby on rails jquery submit a form as js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code in my view:

```
<%= form_for :folder_name, :remote => true, :method => "get", :url => {:action 
    => "show_workflow_list"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :foldernames, options_for_select(@folders, @folders.first), {}, {:onchange => ("this.form.submit()")}%><br /><br />
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'selected_domain', params[:domain_selected] %>
```

When I change the value in the dropdown, the form is being submitted as:

```
Processing by DeploymentGroupController#show_workflow_list as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "folder_name"=>{"foldernames"=>"DETAIL_ADJUSTMENT"
```

When I add a submit button instead of a `:onchange=>` like below:

```
<%= form_for :folder_name, :remote => true, :method => "get", :url => {:action => "show_workflow_list"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :foldernames, options_for_select(@folders, @folders.first)%><br /><br />
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'selected_domain', params[:domain_selected] %>
  <pre><%= f.submit "Submit"%></pre>
```

the request is being submitted like this:

```
Processing by DeploymentGroupController#show_workflow_list as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "folder_name"=>{"foldernames"=>"DETAIL_ADJUSTMENT"
```

I have the following code in my `show_workflow_list` action:

```
def show_workflow_list
  //some code
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and I have a `show_workflow_list.js.erb` file which has the following content:

```
$('#workflow_selection').html("<%=j render "show_workflow_list" %>");
```

The problem is when I change it to `onchange=> submit`, it is processing the action as HTML:

```
 Processing by DeploymentGroupController#show_workflow_list as HTML
```

and not as JS when there is a submit button:

```
 Processing by DeploymentGroupController#show_workflow_list as JS
```

so I'm getting back a 406 status error and the `show_workflow_list` is not being rendered.

---

Update:

I understood why `onchange=>` is being sent as HTML. The reason is that the format for select is "`select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})`". The place i'm mentioning `":onchange=>this.for.submit" is under html_options={}"` which is why it is being submitted as HTML.
I need to render a partial `_show_workflow_list.html.erb` between a `<div>` on the same page, so I changed the code in my controller like this:

```
def show_workflow_list
  //code here
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html{?}
  end
end
```

In the code above, I need to fill something in `{}` the `format.html` so that it will render the partial `_show_workflow_list` between the `div` tags in my `make_deployment_group.html.erb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a JS file you should do this :

```
$('#foldernames').change(function() {
  $('#folder_name').submit()
});
```

And in your controller you should have this :

```
def show_workflow_list
  //code here
  render :format => :js
end
```

When you change the value, it should submit your form so it should send an ajax request to your controller. Your controller should render a js format and execute your `show_workflow_list.js.erb`. To check it, you can use a javascript console like firebug.

Comment: I understood now why that code was not working. it is like this -> "<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/deployment_group/show_workflow_list" data-remote="true" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>" and "<select id="folder_name_foldernames" name="folder_name[foldernames]">" for the above rails code. Now please let me know if i what id should i write in the jqeury code

Comment: Hmmm, ok. You must to add `:html => { :id => "show_workflow_list_form" }` in the form_for method and change `$('#foldernames')` by `$('#folder_name_foldernames')` in the js file.

Comment: I added a new question for this. Please see it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675114/ruby-on-rails-submit-a-form-as-a-js-based-on-a-change-in-select-box) im not able to see any change for the code when i add it in application.js or even in deployment_group.js.coffee

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using the jQuery submit call incorrectly

Check this article...it worked for me
[Rails remote form submit through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340229/rails-remote-form-submit-through-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%= f.select :foldernames, options_for_select(@folders, @folders.first), {}, {:onchange => remote_function(:method => :get, :url => {:action => 'show_workflow_list'}, :with => 'Form.Element.serialize(this)')}%><br /><br />
```

Comment: remote_function is deprecated in rails > 3.0 and iam using rails 3.2.6 [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/remote_function) is the link saying that it is deprecated

Comment: one more thing is that i need to submit the selected value as parameter before calling the the function if write the code i think it will try to execute the code in the action without sending any parameters as im not submitting the form anywhere

Comment: in `with` it is sending all the form parameters value.

Comment: you can find the deprecation solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123325/remote-function-alternative-in-rails-3-1/8970371#8970371)