# Ruby on Rails: Submit a form as a JS based on a change in select box

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following HTML generated by `form_tag` and `select_tag` in Rails:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/deployment_group/show_workflow_list" data-remote="true" id="show_workflow_list_form" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
  <select id="folder_name_foldernames" name="folder_name[foldernames]">
    <option value="RISK_ODS" selected="selected">RISK_ODS</option>
    <option value="DETAIL_ADJUSTMENT">DETAIL_ADJUSTMENT</option>
    <option value="ODS_STAGE">ODS_STAGE</option>
    <option value="FINANCE_DM1">FINANCE_DM1</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Let me know the JQuery code i need to write so that i can submit the form on change of a select value in the drop down. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658326/ruby-on-rails-jquery-submit-a-form-as-js) that when i use :onchange, it is a html option the form is submitted as html and not as a JS form. So, i cannot use :onchange.

I understood that i need to write something like this in my application.js file:

```
$(#folder_name_foldernames).change(function(){
    $(#show_workflow_list).submit()
});
```

I used the above code in application.js file
but i have to remove "require_tree ." as i get some error
so i added

```
$('#folder_name_foldernames').change = () ->
  $('#show_workflow_list_form').submit()
```

to my deployment_group.js.coffee file (the deployment_group is my controller related the above view)

But still i dont see any change when i change the selection in the drop down.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem doing it the following way:

```
<%= f.select :foldernames, options_for_select(@folders, @folders.first), {}, {:onchange=>"myfunc()"}%>
```

and i added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunc()
{
    $('#folder_name_foldernames').change(function(){     $('#this_form').submit(); }); 
}
</script>
```

and the form is being submitted as JS instead of HTML. It would be very helpful if someone can explain me why this is being submitted as JS instead of HTML 
The same code when i write :onchange=> this.form.submit, is being submitted as HTML

Answer (score 0):

If you give an `id` to your `<form>` tag you can use the `id` there.

Like:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/deployment_group/show_workflow_list" data-remote="true" id="this_form" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
<select id="folder_name_foldernames" name="folder_name[foldernames]"><option value="RISK_ODS" selected="selected">RISK_ODS</option>
    <option value="DETAIL_ADJUSTMENT">DETAIL_ADJUSTMENT</option>
    <option value="ODS_STAGE">ODS_STAGE</option>
    <option value="FINANCE_DM1">FINANCE_DM1</option>
</select>
```

and then:

```
$('#folder_name_foldernames').change(function(){
    $('#this_form').submit();
});
```

Don't forget to wrap your selectors in quotes or you'll get a JavaScript error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to repliace 'application.js' by 'application.js.coffee' and add `#= require_self` in the file.

Comment: No, :( it says the same "can't convert Encoding into String
  (in c:/Final/authorize_v1/app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee)" error again when i rename application.js to application.js.coffee and add the following code in my coffee script -> "#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require_self
$('#folder_name_foldernames').change = () ->
  $('#show_workflow_list_form').submit() " Let me know is this script is wrong

Comment: see above my solution to my problem. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: So you can keep you `application.js`, add quotes to your codes like this `"#folder_name_foldernames"` and this `"#show_workflow_list"` and you must yo include jquery.

Comment: sure i did that and it is working now. I will have to post another question related to another problem soon ;)