# how to make js the format of a rails form submitted via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have this form:

```
<div id='relationship_<%= relationship.id %>'>
  <% @value_id = "value_#{relationship.id}" %>
  <% @div_slider_id = "slider_value_#{relationship.id}" %>
  <% @form = "edit_relationship_#{relationship.id}"%>
  <%= form_for(relationship, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <div id="<%= @div_slider_id %>"></div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :value, :id => "#{@value_id}" %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(function() {
    $( "#<%= @div_slider_id %>" ).slider({
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: "min",
      value: <%= relationship.value || 1 %>,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      change: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#<%= @value_id %>" ).val( ui.value );
```

If the user moves the slider, the form is sent as HTML, not JS

```
        $("#<%= @form %>").submit();
      }
    });
    $( "#<%= @value_id %>" ).val( $( "#<%= @div_slider_id %>" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
});
</script>
```

How do I sent that form on JS format when I move the slider?

thanks

Comment: I don't understand. You couldn't send a JS format but you can as for a JS format.

Comment: edited my question for clarity

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem and i posted two questions about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675114/ruby-on-rails-submit-a-form-as-a-js-based-on-a-change-in-select-box). 

It will be sent as html. I solved that problem and wrote the solution in the same post. See if that can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an ID to the form submit :

```
<%= f.submit 'Ready', :id => "button_submit" %>
```

Then in JS instead of this :

```
$("#<%= @form %>").submit();
```

Do

```
$("#buttom_submit").click();
```

Or : try adding a data-type to the form declaration :

```
<%= form_for(relationship, :remote => true, :html => { "data-type" => :js } ) do |f| %>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however I actually want to get rid of the button. I'm going to edit the question to make myself clearer.

Comment: Edited my answer, try the data-type approach

Comment: i ended up using your `$("#buttom_submit").click();` approach, and applying a `display:none` css property to the button. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Set relationship_form id to form

2.
Change this line in your code :

```
$("#<%= @form %>").submit();
```

to

```
$js.post("/relationship.js", $js("#relationship_form").serialize());
```